# Конвертация растрового изображения в векторную графику OpenCV Python

Tags: python, opencv, вектор, конвертация

Есть ли готовое решение конвертации растрового изображения в векторную графику с помощью OpenCV Python? Требуется конвертация изображения с линиями в вектор (отрезки, круги)

Comment: Насчёт пайтона не знаю, но можешь поискать в интернете, может найдешь через пайтон. Точно знаю что есть онлайн сайты для конвертации, по типу convertio.com. есть ещё сайт с готовыми векторными иконками, называется svgrepo.com